# Prepending to existing list created with Rails cycle helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list of comments on my page that is zebra colored to aid distinction between each comment.

I achieve the zebra colouring using the rails cycle helper in the partial I use for each comment:

```
<div class="span9 <%= cycle("odd_response", "even_response") -%>">
```

I dynamically update this list via a form that prepends a new comment to the top of list via AJAX when the user submits a new call.

As I use the same partial as the template to render this new comment the comment is only colored as the "odd_response" irrespective of the color of the previous response i.e. it starts the cycle process again.

How do I get the partial to respect the order of colors present in the table that it is being prepended to?

Comment: You could use JavaScript to choose the class based on the last list item.

Comment: ok, but what would be the best approach to integrating this with the existing cycle helper method. They both use the same partial.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to drop the cycle call and use this CSS for the zebra stripes.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}


tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

This works in all modern browsers, no IE7/8 support.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it needs to be ie7 / 8 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by placing some custom JavaScript in the create.js action that first checked what the background colour of the last comment was and then altered the new comment to the opposite colour immediately after rendering the object on the page.